# tidyverse error while running R Markdown 'package or namespace load failed'

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I wrote and run successfully code in script, and now trying to knit a markdown file.  I kept getting tidyverse error and updated the version of RStudio hoping it would help. It did not. Can someone please help me on how I can solve the error.

```
> library(tidyverse)  
package �tidyverse� was built under R version 3.6.3Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
 undefined exports: %>%
> library(tidyverse)
Warning: package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.6.3
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
 undefined exports: %>%
```

After an update I also get error trying to build plots in script file (I didn't have them before the update):

```
> ggplot(advertising, aes(Daily.Internet.Usage, Age, colour = Clicked.on.Ad)) + 
+   geom_point() 
Warning in (function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480,  :
  unable to open file 'C:/Users/matpo/AppData/Local/RStudio-Desktop/notebooks/F7130DD5-HW3P2_final/1/3023B567657018D6/cd109ty709ig8_t/_rs_chunk_plot_001.png' for writing
Warning in (function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480,  :
  opening device failed
Error in (function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480,  : 
  unable to start png() device
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: What version of R are you running ? Is this on windows? How did you install tidyverse? Have you recently upgraded/updated anything? Does it work when not inside a markdown document?

Comment: Wow, that looks rough. I suggest you start into a fresh R instance (i.e., no `.Rdata`-load, no project), reinstall at least `magrittr`, `dplyr`, and `ggplot2`, and try again.

Comment: @MrFlick yes, I updated RStudio to the latest version :( I update all the packages after that. I use Windows and it doesn't work outside markdown either now (although it worked BEFORE I updated RStudion)

Comment: Not RStudio (the editor) -- R itself. They are different. Usually it shows the R version in the console. Or you can run `sessionInfo()` to check. Also please give the specific version number rather than just "latest version."

Comment: @r2evans did as you recommended, three packages loaded, and then I tried tidyverse and got the the error Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘Rcpp’

Comment: @MrFlick, I am sorry! here is the data on the version R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)

Comment: vethraut, when you get an error like that (and you are trying to use `tidyverse`, then ... install it manually. When an upgrade fails mid-step due to various reasons (including "currently in use"), it can leave that package in a state where it will not be available the next time you start R. So ... restart R, re-install the package, and try again. I apologize that this sounds like a brute-force suggestion to fix the symptoms in a whack-a-mole mindset, but sometimes it's the quickest solution for you.

Comment: @r2evans, thank you! did as you recommended! manually removed all used packages, closed Rstudio, opened again and installed all packaged manually again.Thankfully, didn't have tidyverse error anymore, an error with `in contrib.url(repos, "source") : `, but added `chooseCRANmirror(graphics=FALSE, ind=1)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)` in the beginning of markdown document and it all worked. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Did you have `install.packages()` in your markdown document? That's generally not recommended. It will interfere with packages that you have loaded in your interactive R session. [Some discussion here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rmd-install-packages-best-practices/42591/4).

Answer (score 0):

Met the exactly same problems. The same R version, same error msg, and also kniting a Markdown file.
I solved this by running `library(dplyr)` and `library(ggplot2)`, because I noticed it failed to recognize the piping symbol `"%>%"`, which I remember is in either of these packages.
So it seems that the problem is caused by dependencies between packages? Correct me if I get it wrong.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I am afraid your post is more of a comment than an answer to the question. I'm aware that you cannot post comment for the time being but feel free to ask another question by improving the ones your are commenting on.